# Database_Cleaner Destroying Records between HTTP Requests in the middle of a spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I'm running integration specs using Rspec and Capybara and cleaning out records between specs using Database Cleaner. If it matters, I'm running my specs automatically using Guard and Spork.

Somehow, in the middle of a test run, records are being deleted from the database, causing them to fail.  Have I setup Datbase Cleaner incorrectly? Or am I doing something else wrong? I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034471/factory-girl-capybara-deleting-records-from-database-mid-test) already, but I don't think this is my problem.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is spec_helper.rb

```
Spork.prefork do
  # ...    
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.mock_with :rspec
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
    config.include(MailerMacros)

    config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
    config.filter_run :focus => true
    config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

    config.before(:suite) { DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation }
    config.before(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.start }
    config.after(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.clean }
  end

end

Spork.each_run do
  FactoryGirl.reload
end
```

And here is my spec: (notice the 2 puts statements)

```
feature "Claim Firm" do
  let(:firm) { Factory(:firm, :user_id => nil) }

  scenario "The details page should show a 'Claim' link", :focus => true do
    email = 'claimer@foo.com'
    password = 'secretpass123'
    u = Factory(:user, :email => email, :password => password, :name => "Bob Claimer")
    puts "User Count: #{User.count}" # ==> 1
    visit login_path
    puts "User Count: #{User.count}" # ==> 0
    # The rest of the spec fails because there are no user records...
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm using SQLite in test

Comment: Try changing DatabaseCleaner.strategy to :transaction or :deletion?

Comment: :deletion seems to have worked, but I'm still curious what the root of the problem is. Oh well, this will be fine for now. Thanks!

Comment: Also hit but this behaviour ... did someone find the root of the problem or how to sort it out without changing strategy?

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of. Using :deletion worked, but it was slower. And on another project, I've been using :truncation without any problem. So it's still a mystery to me.

Comment: I have the same issue ang using :deletion does not solve it

Comment: Not sure, but maybe it has to do with the let statement? I have the same problem, however, if I use a before block it works. I guess (didn't check it) that let initiates the variable when you call it, not before. Just a guess.

Comment: hence, using let! fixed it for me ;)

Comment: This is happening to me too using MYSQL. Just a straight up random deletion of stuff. So strange and really nothing different than other tests...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the root cause is, but the truncation strategy for SQLite is an optimization that seems to behave funny in certain situations, so stick with :transaction or :deletion if they're not too slow.